# FFmpegAndroid library rotates video after Compress

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

execFFmpegBinary(new String[]{"-y", "-i", path, "-s", "160x120", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath});

video auto rotate after compress..

is there any solution?

here is lib [Link](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be the autorotate issue in **FFMPEG** and you have to disable autorotate:

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

if this solution doesn't solve your problem, you can get the input video rotation with Android APIs like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
m.setDataSource(inputVideoFilePath);
String rotation;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
     rotation = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
}
```

after finding input file's rotation, you have to rotate the output file accordingly as below :

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i input.mp4 -filter:v "rotation*PI/180" output.mp4
```

Comment: -noautorotate works.. thanks dude
but now height of video is decrease and video is not display proper after compress.. you have any solution?

here is my command

execFFmpegBinary(new String[]{"-noautorotate", "-i", path, "-s", "800x600", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath});

Comment: @BhavinKevadiya i think you are setting output width and height to 800 width and 600 height , and now your output size is different ? , by the way i would appreciate if you accept the answer if it solved your current question

Comment: what if i want default height and width?

Comment: @BhavinKevadiya what if you remove the "800x600" part ? also you can get input video's width and height using METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT and METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH keys in MediaMetadataRetriever class

Comment: Thanks bro. i wil try